# How can i use commons-io 2.4 with Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to write a Jenkins plugin and i was in need of some methods from commons-io that were not available. I am using IntelliJ IDEA and when trying to use `FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs` i was getting error message that the method does not exist. Then I've added the following into my pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

After this i could use the above method and others that were not available before. The plugin compiles without errors or warnings but when i run in in Jenkins i get exception that the motioned is not found:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(Ljava/io/File;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;)Ljava/util/Collection;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(Ljava/io/File;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;)Ljava/util/Collection;
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.my_builder.MyBuilder$1.invoke(MyBuilder.java:118)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.my_builder.MyBuilder$1.invoke(MyBuilder.java:60)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:912)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:885)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.my_builder.MyBuilder.perform(DemandwareBuilder.java:60)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:781)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:562)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1665)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:230)
```

Why does this fail if I've added the dependency to 2.4 version of commons-io? And is there a way to use this more recent version of commons-io for my Jenkins plugin so i can use those methods?

Comment: It's not because you added a compile-time dependency (default scope that you gave), that the dependency will be available at runtime. Accordingly, since your plugin doesn't ship with Commons-io v2.4, Jenkins uses its own, which is in all likelyhood different (you can check your jenkins.war/WEB-INF/lib/ folder).

Comment: The plugin does ship with commons-io v2.4 as if i open it after it gets compiled to .hpi it does have the commons-io.jar (v2.4) in it's WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else also has this issue I've got an answer on jenkins Google group.
All that needs to be done is change the class loader policy. See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+Structure#PluginStructure-Classloader